# WHEN or WHAT is the due date for this assignment?

Tags: word-choice, questions

I want to know due date for my assignment which is given by teacher.
In this situation, is it correct to say

> When is the due date for this assignment?

or

> What is the due date for this assignment?

or other things you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

In casual, every day use, both would be fine, but if you want to be strict, you would either say:

"What is the due date for this assignment" or "When is this assignment due?"

The "what" is asking for a specific name / figure denoting a point in time, and the "when" is actually asking for a point in time - the answer does not have to take the form of a date. For example you could answer "tomorrow", or "in 4 weeks", whereas the first question specifically asks for a date.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. Likewise, What is the DEADLINE? or When is the DEADLINE?

See more examples from the [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/due-date):

> - The new Jan. 22 due date also applies to taxpayers in Washington, Mr Keith adds.
> - The amount and due date will be announced in advance.
> - It was less than satisfying; and yet as his due date neared he kept on, sometimes all night.
> - A loan stock holder is not hampered by such restrictions if his loan stock is not paid on the due date.
> - My first child arrived quite quickly on the due date.
> - The covenant to pay the rent on the due date, quarterly in advance usually, is absolutely fundamental.
> - The due date coincides with the closing ceremonies in Atlanta.
> - Fewer than 5 percent of women deliver on their due date.
> - Only a significantly wrong due date separates Lou Madden from a perfect Super Bowl attendance record.